# MS Office: How to replace with wildcard string

Tags: microsoft-word

I know how to use regex (actually regex like) wildcards to replace an unknown string in word.  But how can I replace that string with itself.  I want to find some string, "(" followed by anything followed by ")" with the same string that existed before, but in bold.  I know how to replace with formatting, but how do I replace a matching set with itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use parentheses ( ) to create groups of wildcard characters and text in the Find What box, and then use \n in the Replace With box to use the results of each expression.
>
> You can use the \n wildcard to search for an expression and then replace it with the rearranged expression. For example, type (Ashton) (Chris) in the Find what box and \2 \1 in the Replace with box. Word will find Ashton Chris and replace it with Chris Ashton.

From https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-and-other-data-in-a-Word-document-c6728c16-469e-43cd-afe4-7708c6c779b7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1